# Correct way to manage multiple h:inputText?

Tags: java, jsf

I've an `h:dataTable` to display my item information (in my case a customer support request) and for each row I'd like to put an `h:inputText` and `h:commandButton` to add a comment to the desired item. I've no problem with action, but my question is about the correct way to manage many `h:inputText` and related value on `backbean`.

I'm not sure that is correct to make all `h:inputText` set the value to the same `backbean` property. Any suggestions? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how the form is composed.

If each row of the table represents one form (i.e. the `h:form` with `h:inputText` and `h:commandButton` is inside `h:column`), then it's technically no problem.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The problem is only that you need to figure to which row the input was related. The `f:setPropertyActionListener` may be useful in this. But this approach hasn't my recommendation. Rather bind the input value (and if necessary also the action) to the iterated row object as declared in `var` attribute of `h:dataTable` instead. I.e. `#{item.value}` and `#{item.submit}`. Or, go for the approach described below.

If the whole table is placed inside a single form (i.e. the `h:dataTable` is inside `h:form`), then you'd better to set the `value` attribute of the `h:inputText` as a property of the iterated row object as declared in `var` attribute of `h:dataTable`.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{item.value}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

When you set it as a backing bean property, i.e. `#{bean.value}`, it will always end up to be the value of the **last** row.

Comment: Thank you BalusC, you are always so exhaustive (I read your blog), I have not thought of putting many forms. Now I try this hint, and also I add an h:inputHiddend for the row id. There are problems that I do not know to put a lot of forms?

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Today I made some tests, but my idea yesterday to use an h: inputHidden was wrong I can not use it.
I do not know the contraindications to use many h:form (or many h:form in to a main h:form)
It was my intention to do something "clean" and do not use strange mechanisms, you believe that I can use without problems?
I believe that my case is real, many rows displayed and the possibility for end-user to add a comment by row (not like in a blog where the comment is "posted" for the displayed item) and some others may have the same need, so I'm looking for the most elegant solution.

Comment: As stated in my answer, either use `f:setPropertyActionListener` to set the row object in question as managed bean property, or put the action method in the iterated row object itself.